# Create Primary/Foreign key relationship in PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have two tables 'CompanyXSales' and 'Market Sales'
Each with a primary key, and no primary key / foreign key relationship between the two.
I would like to create this relationship, and make the link between these two tables, and therefore, add the column 'MarketSalesId' in 'CompanyXSales' where there will be its key relative to 'MarketSales'. To be a relative key, it suffices to check 3 conditions:
-Have the same date
-Have the same amount
-Have the same country

Here is a sample [PowerBiFile](https://filebin.net/ai93ekxqlly5j19v)

How could i proceed that please ? knowing that i already created a "verify" column (with Dax Formula) in 'MarketSales' which equals to 1 if the conditions are verified 0 if not.

Comment: You'll always have order key in CompanyX table right?

Comment: Yes, OrderKey is a unique key that defines an order in my companyX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use merge query in Power Query to get the `OrderKey` Column in `MarketSales` Table.
And then create relationship between both tables.

Please below steps to get the `OrderKey` Column in `MarketSales` Table.

1. Click On Transform Data.
2. Under Combine Tab click on Merge Queries.
3. Select all 3 column and use left join.
4. Click on OK and select the Order Key column as shown below.

[image]

Now you can create relationship between both tables

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just wanted to point out that in my real project i have some imprecision: I have differences of a few minutes on the dates ( yes i also work with dateTime values ), like in CompanyXSales its 01/01/2020 12:10:00 and in MarketSales its 01/01/2020 12:13:00, so is there a way to specify an 'error' of 5/10 minutes in the merge querry?

Comment: No there is no way to specify error at least in power query while using merge queries. but you can do this in your source data. there are some other workaround to get this done.
you can't get solution for everything just in power bi. however Power BI is a great BI tool. having said that somethings need to be done in your source too while importing data.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your help and your time !

Comment: Could you just advice me a tool that could do that ?

Comment: @LougEagle what is your source of data?

Comment: I'm using excel files

Comment: do you have access to database?

Comment: There is no database, i'm only using PowerBi

Comment: I'm looking forward to use powerquery with an advanced DAX formula, i think it could be done

Comment: I found the solution for my problem, by using a CALCULATE function to add a new column using SelectedValues() and Filter() (with a bunch of between conditions)